# Efficient algorithm or python's built-in function to remove sublist from very large list

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I want to remove sublist(20000-80000 elements) from the list containg approx 100000 network addresses as elements in it. I am creating my program in python.

There is 2 method I know:

1. filtering method of python:

   ```
   newl = [x for x in list if x not in sublist]
   ```
2. simple nested for loops

But, both takes lot of time to process in my case.
I need efficient method to solve this which can give fast result.
If any one has any idea or faced this kind of problem, please share. Thanks.

Comment: Convert `sublist` to a set and you should see performance boost.

Comment: Convert them both to a set and do one minus the other.

Comment: Do as Ben says if you **do not** care about order, otherwise do as thefourtheye says ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do an `x in list`, it is an `O(n)` operation. But if you do an `x in set` operation, it is `O(1)` operation since sets maintain hashes internally. So the best way is to compare the alternatives.

```
from random import shuffle, sample
list = range(100000)
shuffle(list)
sublist = sample(list, 20000)
set_sublist = set(sublist)
```

#### List comprehension using list for inclusion checking

The order on list is preserved but lists are slow for inclusion checking.

```
%time newl = [x for x in list if x not in sublist]
CPU times: user 40.8 s, sys: 146 ms, total: 41 s
Wall time: 41.7 s
```

#### Set difference

Fast but the order on list is not preserved.

```
%time news = set(list) - set(sublist)
CPU times: user 16.2 ms, sys: 44 µs, total: 16.3 ms
Wall time: 16.3 ms
```

#### List comprehension using set for inclusion checking

This is only slightly slower than the set difference approach above but the order of the list is preserved and still executes very fast compared to your current approach.

```
%time newl = [x for x in list if x not in set_sublist]
CPU times: user 42.3 ms, sys: 2.95 ms, total: 45.3 ms
Wall time: 44.8 ms
```

Comment: This will break order, might not be an issue but should be warned about.

Comment: @enrico.bacis I think you should add an example for `%time newl = [x for x in list if x not in sublist_set]` which will preserve order and then this answer should be complete.